# lodash: rename key in object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I want to rename key in obj, from this:

```
objs = {
  one: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} },
  two: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} }
}
```

into this:

```
objs = {
  one: { original_description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} },
  two: { original_description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't really need lodash for this. What you need to do is create a new key on your objects with the old value, and then delete the old key. For example:

```
Object.keys(objs).forEach(function (key) {
    objs[key].original_description = objs[key].description;
    delete objs[key].description;
});
```

If you're not familiar with the `delete` operator, see [the MDN documentation for `delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: This method is mutating the original object, find here an immutable version using Lodash https://gist.github.com/LeoAref/9e34436c8b140d690733631befc248ba